# SVG shapes instead of stencils

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm new in mxGraph world and trying to find out how to use SVG symbols with mxGraph in JS. I have a number of SVG files that I would like to use with mxGraph instead of converting each of these to stencils. Is there a way to do that? I have tried using SVG symbol as image in shapes but then I have the problem with connections not going all the way into the symbol.

Any suggestions? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use it as an image `mxImage` can help you.

If you want a special shape for your svg, define it by yourself as a [custom shape](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/shape.html)

or use [svg2xml](https://github.com/jgraph/svg2xml) to create a stencil xml.